# Gradle javaexec task is ignoring jvmargs

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to run my app using a Gradle javaexec task. However, jvmargs and args are not passed to the command execution. Why?

```
task runArgoDev(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "org.app.ArgoDevRunner"
    classpath = configurations.testRuntime
    project.ext.jvmargs = ['-Xdock:name=Argo', '-Xmx512m', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8', '-Dapple.awt.textantialiasing=on', '-ea']
    project.ext.args = ['-initParameter', 'implicit-scrollpane-support=true']
```

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Above code doesn't have the desired effect because it sets extra properties on the `project` object, instead of configuring the task. Correct is `jvmArgs = ...` and `args = ...`. (It's also possible to omit `=`, `[`, and `]`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, javaexec is now using the jvmargs and args

Comment: I'm new to Groovy and I was racking my brain why just omitting '=' didn't work. I wasn't able to put it all together until I found your answer and then it dawned on me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here is example, to pass program args and jvmargs to run task in gradle.

```
run {
    args 'server', 'test.yml'
    jvmArgs '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005'
}
```